# Reading and Writing in C

Tags: c, stdio

so I was messing with the read functions fgets and scanf and with the printing functions write and printf with the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    int n = 0; scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("The input number is: %d\n", n);
    printf("Please enter a string now: ");
    char buffer[200];
    read(0,buffer,200);
    printf("The input string is: %s", buffer);
    printf("which is: %s\n", buffer);
    printf("Now please enter another message: ");
    fgets(buffer,200,stdin);
    write(1,buffer,200);

    return 0;
}
```

I would get these errors:

1-After the first scanf, it won't just show me the message to input the string.

2-What I write now it's what it's going to be saved in the string.

3-It will skip the last fgets...

An example of output:
[image]

Which doesn't make any sense at all; I would like to get an output like this:

```
Enter an integer: 15
The input number is: 15
Please enter a string now: This is the message1
The input string is: This is the message1 which is: This is the message1
Now please enter another message: This is the message2
This is the message2
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `read` does not add null terminator to your `buffer`

Comment: and `write` output the whole `buffer`, also not initialized items.

Comment: Don't post images of text. Post text as text!

Answer (score 4):

Interesting question.  Mixing standard I/O (`scanf()`, `fgets()`) and file descriptor I/O (`read()`) on the same underlying file descriptor (0 aka standard input; `stdin` as a file stream) is at best problematic.  You will get odd-ball effects.

At the file stream level, there is some synchronization between `stdin` and `stdout` when the input comes from a terminal; pending output on `stdout` is often flushed by the library.  When you use `read()`, there is no such synchronization.  That's why the prompt doesn't appear until after you hit return.

When you type `1` for the number, you also supply a newline.  Standard I/O buffers the newline; it is kept so that the next file stream operation can read it.  Then you read a line with `read()`.  This does not know about the standard I/O buffer, so it waits for a new line of input from the terminal.  You need to capture how much data was read because the input was not null terminated; that's a service provided by the standard I/O library, not the low-level `read()` function.

When you then call `fgets()`, it reads the newline that was buffered (not processed by `scanf()` when reading the integer) and returns with the empty line.

Note that if you had any buffered output waiting on standard output (e.g. you had used `printf("Beginning of line: ");` with no newline), then the output from `write()` would appear before the information buffered on `stdout`.

Using `fread()` and `fwrite()` would give you direct binary I/O (no null termination, for example), but would use the same I/O buffers as functions such as `printf()` and `fgets()`.  You get hybrid behaviour when using these — it is normally best to use either `fread()`/`fwrite()` or the text I/O functions on a single file stream, and not both, but mixing them is permissible, relatively simple to understand, and occasionally useful.

So, what you see is all explainable, but it is hard work doing the explaining.  It is also a clear indication of why you should not, in general, mix file stream and file descriptor I/O on the same underlying file descriptor — especially not standard input.

Comment: Nice answer. Perhaps mention the use of `fread` on `stdin` as well? Although `fread` won't null-terminate the buffer either, at least it will be synchronized with other stuff reading from `stdin`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: Good idea; I've added a paragraph on the topic.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Why not use `scanf` with some better formatting:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc,char *argv[]) {
    int n, i;
    char buffer[200], ch;

    printf("Enter an integer: ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    printf("The input number is: %d\n", n);

    printf("Please enter a string now: ");
    scanf(" %[^\t\n]s",buffer);

    printf("The input string is: %s", buffer);
    printf("which is: %s\n", buffer);

    printf("Now please enter another message: ");
    scanf(" %[^\t\n]s",buffer);

    printf("%s", buffer);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
read(0,buffer,200);
```

reads up to 200 characters but it won't add a terminating null character to `buffer`. Hence the following call to `printf` results in undefined behavior.

You need to add code to capture the return value of the function and make sure to null terminate the string.

```
int n = read(0, buffer, 199);  // Leave one for the terminating null character
if ( n == -1 )
{
   // Deal with the error.
}
else
{
   // null terminate the string.
   buffer[n] = '\0';
}
```

Comment: Not so; `read(0, buffer, 200);` on Unix systems where the input comes from a terminal will return the number of bytes available in the input buffer, up to the limit 200.  If there were multiple lines queued up, then multiple lines will be returned; if there's one line with just a newline, then one character will be returned; if there are no characters available yet, it will wait until characters are made available.  You're right it won't null terminate the string. It is crucial, therefore, to capture the return value so you know about errors (`-1`), EOF (`0`) or the actual data length (`> 0`).